# Django forms and __self__ weird rendering

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to render a form form this model:

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, related_name="match")
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, related_name="market")
    invested = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    profitLoss = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.invested

    def divide(self):
        return (int(self.profitLoss) * 100) / int(self.invested)
```

But this form is not rendering if I uncomment this:
`"#+ ' - ' + self.matchTime"`
from this model (**self**):

```
from django.db import models
from team.models import Team
from competition.models import Competition

class Match(models.Model):
    competition = models.ForeignKey(Competition, related_name="competition")
    homeTeam = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="home")
    awayTeam = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="away")
    matchTime = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.homeTeam.team_name + ' vs ' + self.awayTeam.team_name #+ ' - ' + self.matchTime
```

Some guess of this weird behaviour?

Kind regards,

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you called `str(trade)` in your view, you would get a `TypeError`. The problem is that `self.matchTime` is a date object, and in Python, you cannot concatenate date objects and strings together.

The simplest fix would be to convert the date to a string first:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.homeTeam.team_name + ' vs ' + self.awayTeam.team_name + ' - ' + str(self.matchTime)
```

However the recommended approach would be to use string formatting:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{} vs {} - {}".format(self.homeTeam.team_name, self.awayTeam.team_name, self.matchTime)
```

Comment: Thank you for you fast reply Alasdair!

I understood the problem and i've already fixed with your solution!

Thank you!